# Comma after "intuitively" at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: commas

In the following sentence, do I have to put a comma after "intuitively?":

> Intuitively, it represents the concept of something.

Comment: In its current form, this seems like a proofreading question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you would. "Intuitively" here is a introductory phrase, specifically, an adverb.

Such introductory phrases or clauses, [need to be set off with a comma](http://www.english-the-easy-way.com/punctuation/introductory-phrases-clauses-a-words-with-commas). Examples include:

> Barking insistently(introductory clause), the dog ran round the tree.
>   Unsteadily, he opened the box.

Edit: This [site](http://www.english-the-easy-way.com/punctuation/introductory-phrases-clauses-a-words-with-commas) provides the rules:

> Introductory clauses, phrases and words are:
>
> Clauses, phrases or words that are not sentences.
>
> Clauses, phrases or words that provide extra information.
>
> The sentence makes sense with out the clause, phrase or words.
>
> Clauses, phrases or extra words that come at the beginning of the sentence.
>
> They are used as background information, extra information.
>
> There can be more than one introductory clause, phrase or word in a sentences.
>
> Commas are placed after the introductory clause, phase or words. If there is more than one introductory clause, phase or words a comma is placed after each introductory clause, phase or words.
>
> Examples:
>
> > Wow, that was a great movie.

Comment: Can you provide a working link, please.

Comment: The article I've quoted at the previous thread (after Kolln) advises: 'It is permissible, even commonplace, to omit a comma after most brief introductory elements — a prepositional phrase, an adverb, or a noun phrase: Yesterday afternoon we sat around waiting for Bill to arrive. / By evening we had become impatient. / Jauntily he walked into the hall.' [/ Carefully he opened the box.] However, 'intuitively' in 'Intuitively, it represents the concept of something.' is a [modal] pragmatic marker and thus requires the comma.